# Как сохранять последнее текстовое сообщение боту в телеграм в переменную?

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Хочу сделать бота для телеграм, который будет запрашивать у пользователя в чате ввести слово, а на выходе давать случайный заголовок с этим словом. Как сделать, чтобы slovo = последнее сообщение от пользователя?

Например, он ввел "боты" - получил заголовок "Почему боты это плохо".

```
zagolovki = ("Где почитать о " + slovo, "Что надо знать о " + slovo, "Почему " + slovo + " это плохо")

random_zag = lambda: random.choice(zagolovki)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def handle_text(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, random_zag())
```

Comment: Каким методом получаете обновления?

Answer (score 1):

Получилось так:

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def handle_text(message):
    slovo = message.text
    zagolovki = ("Где почитать о " + slovo, "Что надо знать о " + slovo, "Почему " + slovo + " это плохо")
    random_zag = lambda: random.choice(zagolovki)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, random_zag())
```